# What does the phrase "to spin the Payload Event Wheel" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-structure, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "to spin the Payload Event Wheel" in the following sentence from the description of the game FRAG Pro Shooter:

> Starting in November for five days, take part in the Payload Mode
> Event; there’s a special bundle available with event tickets **to spin
> the Payload Event Wheel**, along with one or many big chests.

Also, I am confused about the phrase"along with one or many big chests". Does the phrase mean that the special bundle is available along with chests? Or are bundle and chests two separate entities here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Payload mode" is an shoot-'em-up game. This company is organizing an event, possibly to promote the game. "spin the wheel" generally refers to games of chance. "chest" is a large, strong box that may contain valuables.

Perhaps there will be a lottery of some kind as a part of the event, and you can win one of the prizes (chests).